# Hair region boundary detection using image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want check if forehead is visible in given facial image or is covered by hairs. For this, I need to get boundary of hairs that are falling on the forehead. I tried to use Sobel operator and the dilation to get the boundary but what I am getting is only the boundary around whole face and not the boundary of hairs falling on forehead. I am using otsu's algorithm to threshold the image. Background in my image is white and hair color is black.

Can you suggest how can I get the boundary for hairs on forehead? I know grabcut works but it takes more time to extract the hair portion.

Thank You!

Comment: Hi I know its pretty old now. I also have the same problem, can you guide me what technique worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

1. use face haarcascade to detect face.
2. use eye cascade to detect one or both eyes .
3. expand the region of face from top .
4. estimate for had using eye point and face position.
   this is the simplest way to detect forehead ...

Comment: :I am already able to detect forehead region.What I want is the boundary of hairs falling on forehead.

Comment: if you want to extract or segment hairs then use image alpha mating,best segmentation technique according to me.There are many paper available if you google it you will find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have forehead region, i have couple of alternative suggestions.

1. Use canny edge detector. If the skin colours is different from hair , it should work.
2. If above is not enough, use [local binary pattern](http://www.cse.oulu.fi/MVG/Downloads/LBPMatlab) on the forehead region. This along with the canny edge image should do it for you.